# jquery each div add remove class infinity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

want to create infinity loop that adds class to each div with some timeout

for know have like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.small-bordered-box').each(function(i) {
    var $t = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $t.addClass('active');
    }, 2000 * i);
  });
});
```

```css
.small-bordered-box {
  display: block;
  height: 118px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #3e3b38;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.small-bordered-box.active {
  animation: shake 0.83s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test1</a>
</div>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test2</a>
</div>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test3</a>
</div>
```

want to keep effect like this, just that it would go infiny time.. 
that users would always sees this effect no matter what or where they are on the page..

Comment: so what problem you are facing?

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: What's your issue here...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to shake it with an interval of element's-length*Timeouts-interval i.e. `3*2000` like,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function shakeIt() {
    $('.small-bordered-box').each(function(i) {
      var $t = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $t.addClass('active');
      }, 2000 * i);
    });
  }
  shakeIt();
  setInterval(function() {
    shakeIt();
    $('.small-bordered-box').removeClass('active');
  }, $('.small-bordered-box').length*2000);
  
});
```

```css
.small-bordered-box {
  display: block;
  height: 118px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #3e3b38;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.small-bordered-box.active {
  animation: shake 0.83s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test1</a>
</div>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test2</a>
</div>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @Scorpioniz (y) :) YOu are free to put a tick mark on it.. :D

Comment: waiting for time to do it.. :D

Answer (score 1):

use   `$t.toggleClass('active');` keep this inside setInterval()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.small-bordered-box').each(function(i) {
    var $t = $(this);
    setInterval(function() {
      $t.toggleClass('active');
    }, 2000 );
  });
});
```

```css
.small-bordered-box {
  display: block;
  height: 118px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #3e3b38;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.small-bordered-box.active {
  animation: shake 0.83s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test1</a>
</div>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test2</a>
</div>
<div class="small-bordered-box ">
  <a href="#">test3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: your snippet shows that all blocks are shacking.. not one by one :) 
correct answer for my question is @Rohan Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS into:

```
.small-bordered-box.active {
  animation: shake 0.83s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
```